# TypeError: 'instancemethod' object is not iterable (Python)

Tags: python, multithreading, typeerror, caesar-cipher

I am pretty new with python and threading. I am trying to write a program which uses threads and queues in order to encrypt a txt file using caesar cipher. The encrypting function works well on its own when I use it exclusively, but I get an error when I use it in my program. The error starts from this line:

```
for c in plaintext:
```

And here is the whole code:

```
import threading
import sys
import Queue

#argumanlarin alinmasi
if len(sys.argv)!=4:
    print("Duzgun giriniz: '<filename>.py s n l'")
    sys.exit(0)
else:
    s=int(sys.argv[1])
    n=int(sys.argv[2])
    l=int(sys.argv[3])

#Global
index = 0

#caesar sifreleme


#kuyruk deklarasyonu
q1 = Queue.Queue(n)
q2 = Queue.Queue(2000)


lock = threading.Lock()

#Threadler
threads=[]

#dosyayi okuyarak stringe cevirme
myfile=open('metin.txt','r')
data=myfile.read()


def caesar(plaintext, key):
    L2I = dict(zip("ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ", range(26)))
    I2L = dict(zip(range(26), "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ"))

    ciphertext = ""
    for c in plaintext:
        if c.isalpha():
            ciphertext += I2L[(L2I[c] + key) % 26]
        else:
            ciphertext += c
    return ciphertext

#Thread tanimlamasi
class WorkingThread(threading.Thread):
    def __init__(self):
        threading.Thread.__init__(self)

    def run(self):
        lock.acquire()
        q2.put(caesar(q1.get, s))
        lock.release()

for i in range(0,n):
    current_thread = WorkingThread()
    current_thread.start()
    threads.append(current_thread)

output_file=open("crypted"+ "_"+ str(s)+"_"+str(n)+"_"+str(l)+".txt", "w")

for i in range(0,len(data),l):
    while not q1.full:
        q1.put(data[index:index+l])
        index+=l
    while not q2.empty:
        output_file.write(q2.get)

for i in range(0,n):
    threads[i].join()

output_file.close()
myfile.close()
```

Would appreciate any help, thanks in advance.

Comment: This doesn't really have anything to do with multithreading, it's a plain syntax error. I guess `q2.put(caesar(q1.get, s))` should be `q2.put(caesar(q1.get(), s))`?

Answer (score 6):

In your code you are using `q1.get` and `q2.get` which are function objects. Instead call it with parenthesis:

```
q1.get()
```

which will fetch the value from the [Queue](https://docs.python.org/2/library/queue.html).

As per the [`Queue.get()` document](https://docs.python.org/2/library/queue.html#Queue.Queue.get):

> Remove and return an item from the queue. If optional args block is true and timeout is None (the default), block if necessary until an item is available.

Comment: Even though I resolved this issue thanks to you, my program still doesn't write on the output file I need (the file which needs to contain ciphered text of the txt file: metin.txt as indicated in the program). 

This is a problem different from the one I asked but I would appreciate if you could help on this as well, thanks

Comment: Thanks and sleep well! :)

Answer (score 2):

You're passing Queue.*get* [the function] to caesar instead of the value from calling Queue.*get()*.

Add some '()' and you should be fine. :)